# Google developers console API

Tags: credentials, google-apis-explorer, google-identity-toolkit

Is there an API to manage Google developers console projects and creating credentials, f. e. creating/managing an OAuth consent screen?
I only know that **Google Cloud Resource Manager API** allows to create projects.
[image]